# Sound amplification through a marine speaker

Tags: arduino, amplifier, sound

Trying to get these old marine speakers to be much louder than they currently are. This was apparently done in the past so the answer should be out there. There was a 30 year old circuit that was so corroded I couldn't reverse engineer what had been done.

Power supply (12V battery per rig)
Marine speakers (2 per rig, 15 W 8 ohms)

I have been trying to use an Arduino Nano with the Tone Library to send the tone (using an motor controller H-Bridge to control the 12V to mimic the tone coming from the Arduino just with greater voltage). This is broadly successful but not loud enough.

I then tried to use a boost converter but that appears to up the voltage without producing greater volume (I assume because of a loss of current, but am unsure).

I have also tried using an LM386 signal amplifier to little to no effect.

Any and all help would be appreciated. Messing with sound is new to me and I am at a loss.

EDIT: The original circuit did not use a microcontroller, it was using ICs (I think), some phets (I think), capacitors and a few other components to create a tone with a second-ish delay in between them.

Comment: An LM386 is going to get you less than 1W @ 12V, despite some Amazon sellers claiming 10W. Are you looking to build something or for a recommendation on what amplifier to buy?  Buying recommendations are off topic here.

Comment: @GodJihyo I am looking to build something. But if there is something to buy that will do the trick I am not necessarily opposed. Thank you for your response so far :D, it is helpful.

Comment: Can you describe what the finished units are going to be? Are these something like a box with two speakers, a battery, an amp and something to generate some tones? What are they used for? What is your skill level, are you able to build from scratch soldering individual components or would you need something more modular?

Comment: @GodJihyo These are going to be floating in a barrel (essentially) with a batter, some sort of signal generating thing, an amp, with the two speakers on top. This is for a regatta for the blind, so I need to be able to have different tones and different timings in between. I am able to build from scratch soldering individual components.

Comment: Should clarify, there will be multiple floating barrels, each with the aforementioned components.

Comment: An ordinary linear amplifier powered from 13.8V and driving an 8 ohm speaker on one of the speaker's wires and the other speaker wire at ground produces an output power of only 1.7 Watts or less. A modern bridged class-D amplifier (TPA3116D2) powered from 13.8V and driving an 8 ohm speaker produces an output power of 13 Watts. Most online Chinese places sell a TPA3116D2 amplifier board at a low price.

Comment: @Audioguru This is very helpful thank you.